# Can it have different client secret for different scope?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

If a client allows the following scopes, can it have different client secret for different scopes (e.g. secret1 for the "opened" and "profile" and secret2 for the "api2")?

```
  "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "api2" ],
```

I mean can it limit the client with secret1 to access the opened" and "profile" scope only, but not the "api2" scope and client with secret2 access the "api2" scope only?   If not, what is the right way to achieve it?

From what I have read, the client secret is used to authorize access to the token endpoint.  Client with secret1 or secret2 can create token of any of the allowed scopes.

If that is the case, what is the use cases for client with more than one secret?  Why not have one secret only to access all allowed scopes.